# nmcli radiow wifi on command not enabling wifi for new Ubuntu install

Tags: networking, wireless, nmcli

I'm sort of new to Linux and Ubuntu.

When I run the nmcli radio wifi command, I get the disabled message. When I then set it to nmcli radio wifi on, it doesn't change it from disables to enabled.

I've read that calling "sudo ifconfig wlan0 up" could help, but i'm getting an error: "wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device"

I'm so lost. This is literally my first day using a Linux machine. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a wireless switch or key combination on the computer?

Comment: There's the fn + f5 key that I think is supposed to enable/disable connection. I've played with it and checked if either way it would allow me to enable, but it doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: When I call "rfkill list" I get a Wireless Lan header with the attributes : Soft blocked: no, Hard blocked: yes

Comment: What kind of computer is it? Brand, model. What is the result of: lsmod | grep wmi  ?